# Check if Google has finished displaying results

Tags: jquery, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am writing this Chrome extension app which is supposed to trigger an action whenever Google has finished displaying results.
I can tell that the Google result is contains in div#main.

Based on this, how can I check if the Google search page has finished loading?

This works great only if the whole has been refreshed but does not work when the user select one result from the list of suggested results.

```
$('#main').one('DOMNodeInserted', function() {
    console.log('done updating');
});
```

Any idea about how to go about this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try running your binding code after Ajax calls complete.

```
$(function () {
    bindingCode();
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
        bindingCode();
    })
});
```

Whre the `bindingCode` function contains your code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but no luck.